# C++ Помощь с выводом максимума

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    int n;
    float m;
    float max = 0;
    int tek = 0;
    scanf_s("Введите числа %d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("Введите число %f ", &m);
        if (max < n)
        {
            max = n;
            tek = i;
        }
    }
    printf("Число - %f, Номер - %d", max, tek);
}
```

Ошибка - почему при вводе числа он в любом случае сразу выводит конец , как исправить? Спасибо

Comment: А кто вы хотите добиться этим? `scanf_s("Введите числа %d", &n);` Тогда вы должны вводить именно `Введите числа 15`, скажем, а не просто 15 :) Текст выводите `printf` - типа, `printf("Введите числа "); scanf("%d", &n);`

Comment: @harry здравствуйте , а почему номер элемента максимального неправильно выводит?

Comment: А вы вообще введенные числа (значение m) с чем-то сравниваете?... Вы считали число m, сравнили в очередной раз `max` с `n`, и вводите новое `m`. Так что что вы ни вводите, а выведет оно вам `n`...

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    float m;
    float max = 0;
    int tek = 0;
    printf("Введите числа ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Введите число: ");
        scanf("%f", &m);
        if (max < m)
        {
            max = m;
            tek = i;
        }
    }
    printf("Число - %f, Номер - %d", max, tek);
}
```

Только если все введенные числа будут не больше 0, ответ вас опять же удивит. Подумайте, почему...

Comment: Наверное, нужно заменить знак `<=` на `<`,  либо начинать с единицы, а то `n+1` чисел получается.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Да, конечно. Спасибо, не обратил внимания. Впрочем, в данном случае ничего опасного - типа выхода за границы массива - не происходит...